# Can I switch the mouse buttons in Terraria?

Tags: terraria

I'm left-handed. I wish to swap the left and right mouse buttons.

How can I do so for this game?

Comment: I thought this was a system setting?

Comment: @GnomeSlice One would be led to believe so, however a quick google search reveals that this is a known bug/issue. System settings for some reason do not affect Terraria. Most solutions I have seen seem to rely on a script of some sort to capture and swap clicks as they are input.

Comment: This is a well known problem for lefties. Ubisoft have a lot of games that don't care avec system settings in the menu. Sometimes, I endup tweeking my Razer mouse driver to set a profile for the game. But this must be resolved.

Comment: Some (gaming) mice allow one to "hardware swap" the buttons so that the computer acually sees the left button as the right one and vice-versa.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used my Mouse drive to do so (Razer Lachesis). It can be bind by profile, by application. Work great without real 3rd party.

Comment: So how is this specific mouse and its driver software *not* third-party stuff?

Comment: It is, no doubt about it. It's just not in my context as the driver was already installed.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think this is possible with the game settings alone.

You could use [AutoHotkey](http://www.autohotkey.com/) to do so. Here's a quick script that switches the left and right mouse buttons back and forth via <kbd>Ctrl-Alt-L</kbd> (for the entire system, though).

```
#NoEnv
#KeyHistory 0
#SingleInstance force

SetBatchLines, -1
ListLines, Off
SetMouseDelay, -1

Suspend, On
LButton::RButton
RButton::LButton

^!l::
Suspend, Toggle
return
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try to use an utility to [remap the mouse](http://www.autohotkey.com/docs/misc/Remap.htm) buttons. This will of course switch them system-wide, so it might be a bit less practical.